# Is there any option to restore data after deleting from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, restore

There are some rows in a table, by mistakenly I had deleted all rows from the table and data got commited. So is there any way to restore data for that table.

I am not having backup of the database.

I did not enable Binary Logging.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the database?

Answer (score 3):

If you had replication (or binary logging) enabled (`log-bin` option), then you could recover your data (or part of them) by replaying binary logs.

If you have some backup (and recorded binary log position from time of backup), you need recover a backup and then replay logs from position, when backup was taken.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a backup, then NO. The data is lost.

I suggest you learn about the `--i-am-a-dummy`-option and turn off autocommit.

Comment: autocommit doesn't help, when table is stored in engine, which doesn't support transactions (eg. MyISAM was the default before 5.5).

Comment: Small effort to change it to a type that does...